# Access Device Camera in Unity

Tags: google-project-tango

I need to get the Android Camera parameters like focal & exposure from Unity.

I'm using the Tango AR Camera in my Project and using the Unity AndroidJavaClass I can get the Camera class, get number of cameras, and open a camera for more options.
However, when I call the Camera.open() method the app camera stops showing the feed, probably since the open() method disconnect the camera from the Tango AR Camera.

Can the Camera shared/accessed both from my code only to get cam. parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the Tango API and Android Camera API together. Tango occupies the camera hardware, which means that the Camera.open would not get a handle of the camera.

To get intrinsics, you might want to go through the Tango API.

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics intrinsics = new TangoCameraIntrinsics();    
VideoOverlayProvider.GetIntrinsics(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, intrinsics);
```

TangoARScreen is doing something similar, see [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/c1f34f98b05d29918f6f338204537832da08a0fc/TangoWithMultiplayer/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoARScreen.cs#L170).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the focus distance.
Also, exposure is not available in the TangoCameraIntrinsics.

If I could get a reference to the Android Camera I would call camera.getParameters() and get all the info I need.

Comment: If you are setting the camera to auto exposure, the exposure is not query-able in runtime. But if you have a fixed exposure, you could set it through the `TangoConfig` object.